# From completable to observable RxJava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have the method which return completable

```
interface MyClass{
  fun getSomething(): Completable
}
```

I would like to map it to `Observable.just(true)` if it is complete or `Observable.just(false)` if it is not complete/error.

something like this (pseudo code)

```
  getSomething().doIf {
       if (it.onComplete){
          return Observable.just(true)
    } else {
          return Observable.just(false)
    }
}
```

Is there something like my made up method `doIf` ?

I was trying to achieve it using `Observable.fromcallable{}` or `myClass.getSomething().toObservable` but nothing works.

Is is possible to achieve that and how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to Single, then to Observable:

```java
getSomething()
.toSingleDefault(true)
.onErrorReturnItem(false)
.toObservable()
```

or convert to `Observable` and flatMap the signals

```java
getSomething()
.toObservable()
.flatMap(
    { Observable.never<Boolean>() }, 
    { Observable.just(false) }, 
    { Observable.just(true) }
)
```

Comment: second option doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work how?

Comment: after edit works :P